# Markers don't appear after query runs

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a website in which a user can choose from a dropdown menu a value. After clicking the button a request with ajax is send to the server and I get as a result some text (I use ajax cause I don't want the page to refresh). 
The problem appears when I want to use the googlemaps api in order to get - together with the text - a map with some markers on it. I am trying to add the corresponding code for creating the markers in the success function of the $.ajax but it doesn't seem to work. Actually I don't know if this is the correct way.

I will post here the part of the code that I add in the success function:

```
$.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'activities_code.php',
      data: {datastr:datastr, datastr1:datastr1},
      success:function(response){
                $("#msg").html(response);


  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
 zoom: 14,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
 mapTypeControl: false,
 mapTypeControlOptions: {
style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
},
navigationControl: true,
navigationControlOptions: {
style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
}
});
<?php
$category = $_POST['category'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT activities,city,latt,lonn FROM activities where     activities='$category'");     
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$name=$row['activities'];
$lat=$row['latt'];
$lon=$row['lonn'];
$desc=$row['city'];
echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<b>$activities</b><br/>$city');\n");
}
?>
center = bounds.getCenter();
map.fitBounds(bounds);              
            }        
   });

 });
});
```

In the php part I echo

```
   echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<b>$activities</b><br/>$city');\n");
```

Where addMarker is this function:

```
 function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
 var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
 bounds.extend(pt);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: pt,
 icon: icon,
 map: map
 });
 var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: info,
 maxWidth: 300
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
 if (currentPopup != null) {
 currentPopup.close();
 currentPopup = null;
 }
 popup.open(map, marker);
 currentPopup = popup;
 });
  google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
 map.panTo(center);
  currentPopup = null;
 });
 }
```